# Is editing tags enough to quality for the Illuminator badge?

Tags: support, editing, badges

The [Illuminator](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/badges/136/illuminator) gold badge description says:

> Edit and answer 500 questions (both actions within 12 hours, answer score > 0)

Is editing the tags of a question enough for the purposes of qualifying for this badge, or does the edit need to actually be the title or body of the question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Editing tags is not enough

From the [general meta on badge earning](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/68258/404165), you can find the Illuminator family of badges details which include:

> Only body and title edits on the question count, tag-only edits do not.